# How to see nodes CPU usage in ROS?

Tags: ros, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I built an autonomous car simulation in Gazebo. But for some reason my simulation runs with a very low time rate (around 0.1 off the real time) .

My program includes a number of different nodes and I suspect that some of those nodes use considerably more CPU than others.

The question is : **Is there a way to see the CPU usage of each running node ?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52060/how-to-see-nodes-cpu-usage-in-ros-?/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since normal nodes are started as distinct processes a simple `top` or `htop` should do the trick.

Sadly i dont know of a way to see the load if you are working with nodelets that reside within the same process. Maybe someone else can shed some light, if this is even possible? (Other than starting the nodelets in different managers and making them distinct processes?)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2013-01-12**:
The only way to see the CPU load of a nodelet is to start it in a separate process. ROS does not provide any direct means for getting CPU usage.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-12**:
Gazebo, itself, can use a lot of CPU cycles, depending on how detailed your simulation model is. A good place to start is checking the CPU load for those processes. We created simpler models for when we need more robots or better performance, saving the detailed models for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Ben_S says in his answer, the best place to start is `top` or `htop`. If you want more information then I recommend using [sysprof](http://sysprof.com/) so that you can see which function calls are taking the most time and figure out where optimizations can be made. That would even help with nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently wrote a rqt plugin to show process info for running nodes. It's still very much a work in progress, but the basic functionality is there:

<s>https://github.com/OSUrobotics/rostop_gui</s>

UPDATE by @130s: It is released as http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_top

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2